# Host Blazor Consol app in Windows Service?

Tags: web, windows-services, blazor, executable

I got a Blazor .NET 5.0 website inside a console application project, how do I host this in a Windows Service?

I need a exe file for the sc.exe but do only get dll and a wwwwroot. Publishing the webpage does also not help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices nuget in your hosting project. You can create a generic host that can be run as a Windows Service by invoking ['UseWindowsService'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.windowsservicelifetimehostbuilderextensions.usewindowsservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Example .NET Core 3.1/.Net 5:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService();
}
```

In .NET 6 project template for Blazor app hosted in ASP.NET Core it will be a bit different, because `WebApplicationBuilder` is used. `IHostBuilder` can be accessed with `Host` property.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
```

The service can be created using [`New-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2) powershell command. You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I added the nugget to my Blazor consol application project but Im not sure how to implement the UseWindowsService? I do jave a WebAssemblyHostBuilder and webassemblyhost but can´t see how your code would fit here?

Comment: You have to invoke it when you are building the main host that provides the Blazor app. Blazor app has it's own Program.cs that runs in the browser. I edited my example. When the program starts this method checks if it is run as a Windows service. You can read more in the documentation article.

Comment: The Blazor template use WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault, I dont see how you get IHostBuilder from this?

Comment: What projects do you have in your solution? I assumed that you have at least 2: one with the blazor wasm application and second with web server that hosts your application. The hosting server can be run as Windows service, not the blazor app.

Comment: I only got one project, its a .NET 5.0 Console Application(BlazorWebAssembly) and it publish a Blazor with wwwroot. It sounds like I have to create another host project to host my Balzor webproject in and then build this to a exe that can be executed as a Windows Service. What kind of .NET project would I need for this? Regular Consol Application?

Comment: Yes, you need an ASP.NET Core app that will host your Blazor app. You should be able to use the `Server` project created by `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`. Copy it to your solution and change reference to your client app. More about hosting and deployment [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0). This is the first deployment strategy from that article. I'm guessing now the "console application" that you are referring to is a "dev server" that hosts your blazor app when you are running it locally.